# what type of object is returned when calling a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

`I wrote a function that returns a dictionary and then called this function within another function to get a value using key x:

```
def buildCoder():
    return dict

def apply():
    coder=buildCoder()
    new+=coder[x]
    return new
```

why do I get an error message that coder is a function object and thus does not have an attribute `__getitem__`?

Comment: `dict` is a built-in type; what did you expect `dict` to be instead? `dict[x]` would throw `TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `dict` which is built-in function:

```
>>> dict()
{}
```

Hence `buildCoder` is returning a function. This gives you the error at `coder[x]` as `coder` is now a function and doesn't have a `__getitem__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return dict`, you actually return the function that Python uses to *create* a `dict`.  Use `return dict()` to return a dictionary.